# Is the Progress Challenges tab on the world map locked behind story progression?

Tags: tiny-tinas-wonderlands

With my first character, she couldn't seem to access it before Nothinghappenshereshire or thereabouts.

And even making a second character after I could see the Challenges on my first character shows the challenges to exist.

So, am I just mistaken, or is the Progress Challenges tab basically progress- and account-locked?

Comment: I've edited the tag to: [[tag:tiny-tinas-wonderlands]] since this question appears to be about that game. Let me know if I am incorrect.